# Why CSS height 100% overflow parent?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `#red` element bigger than its parent when its CSS clearly says `height: 100%`?

```css
#black {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height:50px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  height:100%;
}

#grey {
  background-color: grey; 
  height: 100px; /* The height is just used as an exemple, it cannot be known.  */
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="black">
    <div id="red">
      <div id="grey"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because some answers doesn't seem to understand the need, this mean I was not clear on my purpose (my bad, sorry).

What I would like:

The `#red` element to have the same height as its parent, the `#black` element (**so no scroll-bar, no overflow, and no hidden space**). The `#black` element's height may change (**so it cannot have an exact height**) but is bounded with `max-height`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#black` does not have a `height` (it has a `max-height`).

Therefore, all other `height` or `max-height` or `100%` is ignored, because `100%` on unknown is unknown.

The only reason `#red` has a height is because it's child - `#grey` - has a height of `100px`

Change `max-height: 50px` to `height: 50px` on `#black` and you'll see everything work exactly as it should:

```css
#black {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  height:50px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  height:100%;
}

#grey {
  background-color: grey; 
  height: 100px; /* The height is just used as an exemple, it cannot be known.  */
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="black">
    <div id="red">
      <div id="grey"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Now a lot of mysteries I had about CSS are clear =D!  
But do you know if it's possible to make the `#red` element fit its parent while I cannot know its height (of the parent)? Just a `max-height`.. =/

Comment: But I must put you the green V, because you answered the question in the title.

Comment: Why do you want to give `black` a fixed height at all? A parent will automatically contain (all) it's children (and their descendants) if there are no explicit heights set.

Comment: Because I would like it to be bound to a max height. Otherwise it can fill an entire page (or even more), while I want it to maximum fill 50% of the page (for exemple).

Answer (score 0):

The overflow is caused by the height of the `#grey` div, at `100px`.
The `#red` div's height is inherited from the `#grey` div's height.

If you want the `#black` div to have the same or bigger height of its grandchild, do one of these:
1) Increase the `#black` div's size, or
2) Set a fixed height for the `#black` div, such that the `100%` in the child elements can have a point of referral. Currently the `100%` mean nothing, because there is no fixed height in the parent element for it to have a relative size for.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring the height/max-height issue, since it is already written by 2 other answers.

There is a logical problem with what you are trying here,
the red div contains the grey one so it must be bigger than 200px (by 5px at top +5px at bottom), since it has no overflow defined it goes beyond the 100% (90 px).

**To fix this,** set the scrollbar property
overflow / overflow-y
each can be set to any of visible, hidden, scroll, auto, or inherit.

auto - will add scrollbar only if needed
scroll - forces a scrollbar

Comment: Thanks a lot  dude, but I don't want any scroll-bar, or hidden space. I want the `#red` element to fit its parent, like the `height: 100%` should do.